# Pentest pure JavaScript (qooxdoo) Website

Tags: javascript, security, xss, qooxdoo, penetration-testing

I'm wondering how I could Pentest a website made completely in JavaScript, for example using the qooxdoo Framework.
Those websites do not contain any requests to the server which respond with HTML content. Only one Javascript file gets transmitted when loading the page (which is an almost empty html page with just the link to the javascript file) and the page is then beeing set up by the loaded JS file, without any line of HTML written by the developer.

Typically, there would be some Spidering/Crawling in most Web App Scanners (like Nexpose), which check a website for links and forms and crawl any link they find which directs to the same domain and test any parameter found on these links. I assume those scanners would not have any effect on a pure JS page.

Then there's the other possibility: A proxy server (like Burp Suite) which captures any traffic beeing sent to a server and is able to check any found parameters on this requests. This would probably work to test the API-Server which is located behind the Website (for example to find SQL injections).

But: Is there any way to test the client, for example for XSS (self or stored)? 
Or more in general: What types of attacks would you typically need to check in such a pure JS web application? What tools could help with that?

Comment: Not an answer because I don't feel like I have enough knowledge on the matter, but I'd go about testing the client the same way I'd test a desktop app. After all, that's what it is, it just runs inside the browser. The only thing different is that you'd have to analyze mostly obfuscated JS instead of binary code. Testing the services doesn't test the client itself.